# How to get by Id from a repository Class .NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have a repository.cs file like this:

```
private static List<AdminResponse> responses = new List<AdminResponse>();

public static IEnumerable<AdminResponse> Responses => responses;

public static void AddResponse(AdminResponse response)
{
    responses.Add(response);
}
```

I am trying to retrieve an employee for editing from `Employeescontroller.cs`. The employee model has `int Id` as key.

What should I write inside:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
     // What code goes here I cannot figure out :(
     return View();
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To lookup the item you want to display, you can use the Linq method FirstOrDefault, like this:

```
var response = responses.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == id);
```

As your method's input variable id is nullable (the type is int?) you may have to use `id.Value` in the above line.
Before to start searching, you may want to check if that id is not empty, and `return HttpNotFound()` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks mate @johey . I added the following code to Repository.cs:
` public static AdminResponse GetResponse (int? ID)
        {
            return responses.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == ID);
        }`

And the following in the controller:

`public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            AdminResponse adminResponse = Repository.GetResponse(id);

            return View(adminResponse);
        }`

Comment: Good job! 
By the way, if you want to improve your coding skills, you may want to learn asynchronous techniques.. e.g. as explained here: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/async-query-and-save.aspx

Comment: Sure, thanks :) . I started coding from here and there. I knew to do this with db but not with lists :P Anyways will go through it \m/